# Change brightness of CCSprite to simulate time

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I have a bunch of sprites to create a forest in my game. What I want to be able to do is simulate night and day by dimming or brightening each image, as if the sun is down or up. How can I change the brightness (NOT opacity) of a sprite.

I'm using the latest version of Spritebuilder and XCode to create my game

Answer (score 0):

you can use CCActionTintTo action or create your own action